# Is this thing on? (How to tell if my cpuminer is working?)

Tags: mac, cpu-mining, mining-software

I have pretty much no idea what I'm doing. But I've had `cpuminer` running on my laptop for a half hour or so, just playing around. I *know* it's not near worth the time or electricity, I'm just having some fun.

I'm using Slush's pool, and ran the program:

```
./minerd --url http://api.bitcoin.cz:8332 --user <me> --pass <pass> --threads 8
```

And I seem to be generating normal output:

```
[2013-11-27 13:28:05] thread 7: 291732 hashes, 5.18 khash/s
[2013-11-27 13:28:05] accepted: 0/151 (0.00%), 41.48 khash/s (booooo)
[2013-11-27 13:28:08] Stratum detected new block
[2013-11-27 13:28:08] thread 3: 183216 hashes, 5.18 khash/s
[2013-11-27 13:28:08] thread 7: 17988 hashes, 5.28 khash/s
[2013-11-27 13:28:08] thread 1: 38664 hashes, 5.26 khash/s
[2013-11-27 13:28:08] thread 6: 151224 hashes, 5.16 khash/s
[2013-11-27 13:28:08] thread 4: 161664 hashes, 5.18 khash/s
[2013-11-27 13:28:08] thread 2: 79848 hashes, 5.16 khash/s
[2013-11-27 13:28:08] thread 5: 60576 hashes, 5.21 khash/s
[2013-11-27 13:28:08] thread 0: 164808 hashes, 5.17 khash/s
[2013-11-27 13:28:09] thread 3: 5484 hashes, 5.33 khash/s
[2013-11-27 13:28:10] accepted: 0/152 (0.00%), 41.74 khash/s (booooo)
```

But I don't know how long it normally takes for my account to begin displaying any kind of progress:

[image]

My CPU usage is pegged at around 750%, which makes sense - but I'm not sure how I'll know if/when they're contributing to anything.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're using the wrong hash algorithm for Bitcoin mining. Bitcoin uses SHA256d (d = double), but cpuminer (at least the version 2.3.2 on my system) defaults to **scrypt** (for Litecoin) instead:

```
-a, --algo=ALGO       specify the algorithm to use
                      scrypt    scrypt(1024, 1, 1) (default)
                      sha256d   SHA-256d
```

Slush's pool is Bitcoin, so you should add `-a sha256d` to your command line. You'll see a much higher hash rate (scrypt is intentionally much slower to compute than SHA256) and you'll get *yay!!!* instead of *booooo* after some time in your log:

```
[2013-12-09 21:51:25] thread 0: 49985792 hashes, 832.61 khash/s
[2013-12-09 21:51:29] thread 1: 51072988 hashes, 841.16 khash/s
[2013-12-09 21:52:23] thread 0: 49956628 hashes, 864.18 khash/s
[2013-12-09 21:52:32] thread 1: 50469540 hashes, 808.16 khash/s
[2013-12-09 21:53:26] thread 0: 51850904 hashes, 833.58 khash/s
[2013-12-09 21:53:29] thread 1: 48489516 hashes, 855.40 khash/s
[2013-12-09 21:54:25] thread 1: 46821320 hashes, 834.33 khash/s
[2013-12-09 21:54:25] accepted: 1/1 (100.00%), 1668 khash/s (yay!!!)
[2013-12-09 21:54:25] thread 0: 50014552 hashes, 838.40 khash/s
[2013-12-09 21:54:41] thread 1: 13586032 hashes, 850.75 khash/s
[2013-12-09 21:54:41] accepted: 2/2 (100.00%), 1689 khash/s (yay!!!)
```

For best results, you should also use the above mentioned **stratum+tcp** protocol and adjust `--threads` to the number of cores in the system.

Answer (score 3):

try using `stratum+tcp://` instead of `http://` protocol.

`./minerd  --algo scrypt --scantime 33  --url stratum+tcp://[server]:[port] --userpass [username]:[password] --threads 1 --retries -1 -P` works pretty well for me right now.

minerd is from http://optimate.dl.sourceforge.net/project/cpuminer/pooler-cpuminer-2.3.2-linux-x86_64.tar.gz

Comment: What does the `--no-longpoll` flag mean? What is `X-Long-Polling` support?

Comment: Using bitcoin algo sha256d
    ``minerd -a sha256d -o stratum+tcp://[server]:[port] -O [username]:[password]``

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT:** Looks like you're using minerd (which to my understanding doesn't have stratum support.)  Slush's pool requires it [(the FAQ seems to mention this briefly)](https://mining.bitcoin.cz/faq/).

Suggestion: Try using one of the miners listed in the FAQ.

Old post: It looks like new blocks are being generated faster than your machine can complete a single unit of work.

[Perhaps you could provide us with a more complete log file?](http://pastebin.com/)

Comment: Thanks! Pastebin'd log file: http://pastebin.com/nNVJ33YV

Comment: @CraigOtis See my updated answer for another (somewhat more informed) idea.