# Raspberry Pi cpuminer error: -bash: ./minerd: No such file or directory

Tags: raspberry-pi, cpuminer

I created a cpuminer instance for my Raspberry Pi derived from [this tutorial](https://www.novaspirit.com/2017/04/10/cpuminer-raspberry-pi/).  Apparently, I've correctly configured the implementation because I can run the example provided in the README:

```
./cpuminer -u alexanderjsingleton.Pericles -p pass -o stratum+tcp://stratum.slushpool.com:3333 -t cputhreads
```

[image]

Apparently, that command is indeed the example because I'm not seeing any feedback displayed within my slushpool-account dashboard for that worker. 
 However, [according to this StackExchange:Bitcoin post](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/17396/is-this-thing-on-how-to-tell-if-my-cpuminer-is-working), the appropriate cpuminer-syntax should be:

```
./minerd -u alexanderjsingleton.Pericles -p pass -o stratum+tcp://stratum.slushpool.com:3333 -t cputhreads
```

but that command returns the following error:

```
   ./minerd -h --algo scrypt --scantime 33  --url stratum+tcp://stratum.slushpool.com:3333 --userpass [alexanderjsingleton.Pericles]:[password] --threads 1 --retries -1 -P
-bash: ./minerd: No such file or directory
```

In any case, this is my first experiment with actual Bitcoin-mining, so I'd appreciate any guidance whatsoever to start mining on my first block- thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original CPUMiner software made an executable named `minerd`. You are using a fork of the CPUMiner software which changed the executable produced to be named `cpuminer`. The `minerd ...` command will not work because that executable file does not exist as it is not created. If you are looking up any instructions for using CPUMiner and it says to do `./minerd ...`, just do `./cpuminer ...` instead. Note that because you are not using the original CPUMiner software not all example commands and options will be the same or result in the same behavior.

There are multiple reasons that you do not see anything on your Slush dashboard. First of all, you are connected to a Bitcoin mining pool and yet you are using the Scrypt PoW algorithm. Bitcoin does not use Scrypt, so whatever you are mining is invalid. Secondly, your hashrate is so low that you are not finding any shares (besides the fact that they will be invalid as you are using the wrong algo), so Slushpool does not know anything about this your worker as it has not received anything back from it.

Comment: That's how I originally ran it (ie `./cpuminer -u alexanderjsingleton.Pericles -p pass -o stratum+tcp://stratum.slushpool.com:3333 -t cputhreads`) but that doesn't appear to register in my slush-pool dashboard for that worker- so what would be the problem?

Comment: I updated my response.

Comment: Thanks Andrew- I suspected the limitations of my Raspberry Pi 3 out of the box might have something to do with the hash-rate- or lack thereof in slushpool.  Also I think I correctly specified the correct command-line parameters for Bitcoin now- thanks for the correction (ie `./cpuminer -u alexanderjsingleton.Pericles -p pass -a bitcore -o stratum+tcp://stratum.bitcoin.cz:3333 -t cputhreads`).  I've got some AntMiners coming soon! :D

Comment: Your command is still incorrect. You want to do `-a sha256d` not `-a bitcore`. `-a bitcore` does "Timetravel with 10 algos" which is definitely not Bitcoin.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew! `./cpuminer -u alexanderjsingleton.Pericles -p pass -a sha256d -o stratum+tcp://stratum.slushpool.com:3333 -t cputhreads`- I included my process on this [gist](https://gist.github.com/alexanderjsingleton/fd2a4eda9eaefd162c79498d98b1d08f).

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to make the file after building it in the folder. Same thing happened to me.

Comment: Please don't be insulting, follow our Be Nice policy