# What is the best way to earn money mining Bitcoin?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-hardware, mining-profitability

Simply stated- what is the most cost-efficient way to earn money from mining Bitcoin?  I've been a HODL'er since '14 but I recently wanted to deep-dive into mining for fun and was surprised to find how easy it was to do with a Raspberry Pi, slushpool account and a little bit of help from [StackExchange:Bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/60892/raspberry-pi-cpuminer-error-bash-minerd-no-such-file-or-directory).  My question now is- do I build a Raspberry Pi "bucketwheel" equipped with [USB-miner sticks](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B016CWBYJK) like the crate displayed below, purchase an [Antminer S9](https://shop.bitmain.com/antminer_s9_asic_bitcoin_miner.htm?flag=overview) or go to the cloud?  I'd appreciate any guidance or considerations for generating >= $100 month- again this is just for fun in experiment; I'm not looking to become the Hunt Brothers of Bitcoin ;)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mine with your RaspPi or your PC, you'll **lose** money because of electricity fees. The best way to mine is buying a miner (S9 is the best currently), but if you don't want to pay $1500, or don't want a noisy machine at your home, choose **cloud mining**. It's a bit risky, too.

Comment: Thank you- that’s exactly why I said “cost-efficient” I should’ve used asterisks to emphasize.  I might try to do all three for fun.  I appreciate the recommendations.

Comment: @alexanderjsingleton I'd suggest NiceHash. I've tried Hashnest and ViaBTC, While I'm satisfied with Hashnest, don't use ViaBTC.